# How do I make a voice call in iPhone using Trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

I am building an app in which I need to let the user dial a phone number. Looking through the documentation, I could not figure out how to do that. There is a [module for SMS](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/sms.html), but none for voice. Is it possible to make phone calls from your Trigger.io app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `tel:` url, for example:

```
<a href="tel:123">Phone 123</a>
```